# Scroll bar issue in IE when row reordering with data tables

Tags: jquery, datatables

We are using the popular JQuery Datatables plugin as well as its corresponding [Row Reordering](http://jquery-datatables-row-reordering.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/index.html) plugin.

Our datatable contains a scroll bar.

A problem arises in IE8, whereby the scrollbar does not move when you attempt to drag a row from the bottom to the top. This works fine in Chrome and Firefox, and does not produce any JS console error in IE.
I am at a bit of a loss on how to troubleshoot this, so would appreciate any advice on how to get started?

The following is my datatable setup:

```
    <%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1" pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1" %>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
    <%@ taglib prefix="spring" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags" %>
    <%@ taglib prefix="form" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form" %>
    <%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>
    <%@ taglib prefix="fn" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/functions" %>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="<%=request.getContextPath()%>/javascript/jquery/jquery.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="<%=request.getContextPath()%>/javascript/jquery/jquery.blockUI.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="<%=request.getContextPath()%>/javascript/jquery/jquery.cookie.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="<%=request.getContextPath()%>/javascript/jquery/jquery.ui.core.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="<%=request.getContextPath()%>/javascript/jquery/jquery.ui.widget.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="<%=request.getContextPath()%>/javascript/jquery/jquery.ui.tabs.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="<%=request.getContextPath()%>/javascript/jquery/jquery.ui.accordion.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="<%=request.getContextPath()%>/javascript/jquery/jquery.ui.autocomplete.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="<%=request.getContextPath()%>/javascript/jquery/jquery.ui.position.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="<%=request.getContextPath()%>/javascript/jquery/jquery.dataTables.js"></script>    
    <script type="text/javascript" src="<%=request.getContextPath()%>/javascript/jquery/jquery.ui.sortable.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="<%=request.getContextPath()%>/javascript/jquery/jquery.ui.custom.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="<%=request.getContextPath()%>/javascript/jquery/jquery.dataTables.rowReordering.js"></script>
<title>Test reordering</title>
</head>
<body>
    <body onload="setupTables() ;">
    <div id="myDiv" style="height:250px; border:1px; color: blue">
        <table id="myTable">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Element Heading</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td>Element 1</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Element 2</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Element 3</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Element 4</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Element 5</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Element 6</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Element 7</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Element 8</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Element 9</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Element 10</td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>    
        </table>
    </div>
    <script type="text/javascript"> 
        function setupTables() {
            /* $('#myTable').dataTable({
                "sScrollY":"10px",
                "sScrollX":"10px",
                "bScrollCollapse":false,
                "bRetrieve":false,
                "bProcessing":false,
                "bDestroy":true,
                "bServerSide":false,
                "bPaginate":false,
                "bLengthChange":true,
                "bFilter":false,
                "bSort":true,
                "bInfo":false,
                "bAutoWidth":true,
                "bJQueryUI":true,
                "aoColumns":[
                    null,
                    null,
                    null,
                    null,
                    null,
                    null,
                    null,
                    null ]
            });*/ 
            $('#myTable').dataTable({
                "sScrollY":"200px",
                "sScrollX":"1050px",
                "bScrollCollapse":false,
                "bRetrieve":false,
                "bProcessing":false,
                "bDestroy":true,
                "bServerSide":false,
                "bPaginate":false,
                "bLengthChange":true,
                "bFilter":false,
                "bSort":true,
                "bInfo":false,
                "bAutoWidth":true,
                "bJQueryUI":true

            }).rowReordering();
        } 

    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only "solution" I could find for this issue was to include the [scroller plugin](http://datatables.net/extras/scroller/) and following this, the scrolling worked correctly in IE. Will open an issue on the bug tracker

Answer (score 0):

It would help if you provided some code examples or your style sheets. Perhaps its not the javascript but rather your CSS.

Scrollbars on div elements require a width and height to be defined.

Comment: Have updated the post with the datatables configuration. The scrollbar is configured using this plugin

Comment: Perhaps try setting a height for the containing div. Does it scroll at all or does it just not scroll when you try dragging an element?

Comment: I'll try that, it just does not scroll at all in IE

Comment: I remember a bug in IE where if you didn't define a height, overflow wouldn't work properly. The thing is for the Row Reorder plugin is I see multiple elements. Be sure you're applying the parameters to the proper elements.

Comment: I've just confirmed that the above html with no css produces the same results. I just added some sample styling based on your comments

Comment: Maybe you should consider posting an issue on the Issue tracker for the plugin, or perhaps check the bug tracker and see if others have had the same problem.